# Integration with Gmail with Salesforce

Tags: integration

Is there a way to integrate Gmail with Salesforce. Developing our own custom Cirrus Insights or is there any free app that could provide with Gmail with Salesforce Integration ?

Comment: Here is a article may be you are interested https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=google_gmail_activate.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail to Salesforce allows you to automatically log emails and chats you send from your Gmail account as activities on lead, contact, opportunity, and other records that support activity history in Salesforce.
Gmail to Salesforce is based on the Email to Salesforce feature. To activate Gmail to Salesforce for your organization, from Setup, click Email Administration | Email to Salesforce. To configure your personal Gmail to Salesforce setup, from your personal settings click Email | My Email to Salesforce.

- From Setup, click Google Apps | Settings.
- In the Activate Google Apps Services list, click Edit next to Gmail Buttons and Links.
- Select the Active checkbox to activate Gmail Buttons and Links for your organization.
- Select the Gmail Links checkbox to add Gmail links next to all email fields (except email fields on pages under Setup).
- Select the Gmail Buttons checkbox to add Compose Gmail buttons in Activity History related lists on leads and contacts.
- Read the Terms of Use, and select the checkbox indicating you have read and agree to them.
- Click Save.

Reference link: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=google_gmail_activate.htm&language=en_US

Video tutorial for integration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPMGuT84rtk

There's also chrome extension for that: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-integration-fo/fmdomiplhgolgpibfdjjhgbcbkdcfkmk?hl=en

Here's app which is free for first 3 licenses and after that $10/month/user: http://www.ebsta.com/salesforce-gmail-integration/